# Where does quire come from?

Tags: etymology, verbs, irregular-words, compound-verb

Where does the verb *quire* come from?
L&S is unsure of the etymology but compares it to a Sanskrit word.
Do we know more about the etymology of the verb?

Is composed of *ire* ("to go") and another (perhaps unknown) element, or is the conjugation a regularization of something else?
It seems weird to me that *quire* behaves as if it was *qu-* and *ire*, but prefix rings no bell and there seems to be little semantic connection to any kind of going.
Other compound verbs from *ire* are much easier to make sense of.

Comment: de Vaan: *neque it(ur) > nequit(ur) > ne quit(ur)

Comment: @AlexB. Interesting! Does de Vaan argue why it is so and explain how the meaning arose from that origin? If there are any more details to the story, that would be a good answer.

Comment: There were suggested edits to add the tag [tag:negation]. I rejected them on the grounds that the question itself is not about negations and does not even mention *nequire* alongside *quire*. That the answer is related to negation does not affect tagging; tags are for questions, not answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The etymology I've heard, though I can provide no sources on it, is that it started with the idiom *neque it* "he doesn't go yet" = "he cannot" (compare French *ne pas* "not a step" used to negate verbs).

Through regular elision, this then became *nequit* "he cannot".

And once the link to the original *neque* was lost, this was rebracketed as *nē quit*, since *nē* was far more common than *neque* as a negation, and *it* has no real connection to the meaning.

Comment: That *quire* is derived backwards from *nequire* does indeed seem quite plausible, or at least far more plausible than anything I could think of.